# How can I load XML files in Spark 2.2.0?

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I load an xml files in spark-2.2.0 like:

```
var ac = spark.read.format("xml").option("rowTag", "App").load("/home/sid/Downloads/Files/*.xml")
```

It is showing me an error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: xml. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
>     at 
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:549)
>     at 
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:86)
>     at 
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:86)
>     at 
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:301)
>     at
>    org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:156)
>     ... 48 elided
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xml.DefaultSource
>     at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:62)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$21$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(DataSource.scala:533)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$21$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(DataSource.scala:533)
>     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$21.apply(DataSource.scala:533)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$21.apply(DataSource.scala:533)
>     at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:533)
>     ... 53 more

Comment: Have you included/imported `com.databricks.spark.xml._`? See here: https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml

Comment: Yeah.  I am using spark-shell and importing the dependency when starting spark shell  using following
bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.4.1

Answer (score 4):

Here you have to used databricks package for load the XML files. You can load the databricks package using below command with spark-submit or spark-shell.

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.10:0.4.1
```

then you can load as per this.

```
val df = spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rowTag", "app")
  .load("/home/sid/Downloads/Files/*.xml")
```

for more information visit this link. https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml

Comment: when we have already added the dependency for xml, then why should we create spark context as spark-shell already provides spark session as spark. Wouldn't val df = spark.read.format("xml").option("rowTag", "app").load("/home/sid/Downloads/Files/*.xml") be better?

Comment: Yes you have to used spark, sqlcontext is already deprecated I am just giving you example how can you import the package and load the xml.

Answer (score 0):

@sahil desai - when we have already added the dependency for xml, then why should we create spark context as spark-shell already provides spark session as spark.
Wouldn't this be better?

```
 val df = spark.read.format("xml")
         .option("rowTag", "app")
         .load("/home/sid/Downloads/Files/*.xml")
```

Comment: you can add this in comment , next time please take care of this thanks

Comment: @Binit Ghetiya - Well, we started this question for clearing our doubt. Be it a comment or an answer, it should be concerned to the relevant topic right. So, why did you enter the scene being all pedant?

Comment: @BinitGhetiya - See, the thing is I answered the question if you notice properly. But, to maintain the decency of letting the guy keep his point, I said it in such a way. You should atleast see before commenting. And if you don't mind, do you understand the relevancy of the question asked?